# UIElement does not contain a definition for 'Name'

Tags: c#, wpf

This is the code I'm working with:

```
foreach (UIElement child in cnvsLinkScreen.Children)
{
   if (child.Name.Contains("LinkObject");
       cnvsLinkScreen.Children.Remove(child);
}
```

I have the different objects named like "LinkObject1" and "Line1" (plus other types).  I could run several loops and remove by name but I thought this would be easier to do.

When I run the code:

```
        foreach (UIElement child in cnvsLinkScreen.Children)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(child);
        }
```

and break on the Debug; I see the name of the child object listed under the "Name" property in the child object.

However, I can't reference it in the first code example.  I get the compile error:

```
Error   CS1061  'UIElement' does not contain a definition for 'Name' and no accessible extension method 'Name' accepting a first argument of type 'UIElement' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

How do I reference the "Name" property of the UIElement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cast to `FrameworkElement`:

```
foreach (FrameworkElement child in cnvsLinkScreen.Children.OfType<FrameworkElement>())
```

That's where the `Name` property is defined.  A `UIElement` has no `Name` property.